# How to change dynamic text in flash as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm beginner in flash. I created a text from the text_tool in flash. I set the instance name **'mytext'** and text type to dynamic. Now I want to change the text on run time. For example: current text is **'hello world'** now when I run the flash file I want to change the text to ***'any random text'***. So I used following code for this.  `mytext.text = 'any random text';` but on the run time I could see any text. Please help me how to change its text?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for that, Please check for the following:

- If there are multiple frames on your timeline and your `TextField` is extended all over those frames then make sure you have provided the instance name to your `TextField` on all the `KeyFrames` on the timeline.
- If you are using some fancy Fonts, try embedding the fonts, at times non-embedded Fonts create this problem.

Comment: alright its works :D after embedded the fonts i see the text :D... thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

for addition, you can use

your `textfield.appendText();`

good luck for your work :)